# How to use Dropbox API to display complete photo albums?

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku, dropbox-api

I am working on a web-based photo selections/proofing application integrated with dropbox. I am stuck at how to efficiently fetch and display a complete folder in my application of like 3000+ photos. What are the API methods and techniques to achieve this efficiently?

I have tried generating share links individually but it takes ages to load all data on a normal internet connection.Like more than an hour.

Isn't there any method in API to fetch all file links in a single request? With some parameters to fetch them in lower resolution in case of heavy images. I am sure it would reduce the album loading time to less than 5 minutes in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API unfortunately doesn't currently offer batch calls for getting links or thumbnails. We'll consider this a feature request.

Comment: any chances of it being added in the near future? I have surveyed a number of APIs. Dropbox is my pick of APIs for our application but this feature is badly needed... thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if/when this would be added.

Comment: The Dropbox API now offers the ability to get thumbnails in batches:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_thumbnail_batch